# Hardwood Flooring around Floor to Ceiling Windows

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, installation

we are in the mist of installing 3/4" hardwood flooring in the house. The great room has several floor to ceiling windows, including around the front door. In the bedrooms and hallway we did not take off the floor baseboards and instead ran the flooring to the baseboard with a proper expansion gap and then covered it with quarter round.

Now that we are out in the great room, I'm not sure how to run the hardwood and get around the baseboards. If we just ran it to the baseboard like in the bedrooms, there would be too large of a gap to the window framing to cover with quarter round. There also appears to be trim around the windows as well.

Any best practices on what to do in this situation?
[image: Picture of window and door]

EDIT: Here is an additional picture of a piece of hardwood pushed up against the moldings showing the quarter round which has fallen into the gap and the gap made by the window molding.
[image: picture of gaps]

Comment: It's not clear from your picture where the "too large a gap" at the windows comes from.

Comment: sounds like an answer, @SteveSh

Comment: Can you add a close-up photo of the "too large" gap? I don't see anything in this picture that couldn't be dealt with.

Comment: Thanks everyone so far! I've added an additional picture showing the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Turned my comment into this answer:

For the trim around the window (casement molding), I would undercut the bottom of the molding (that is, remove ~3/4" of the molding) so that the flooring can slide under the molding. Or remove the molding, trim off the 3/4" mentioned, install the floor, then reinstall the molding.